# Laravel (4) Redirect::action() query parameters are being encoded

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm not having the issue locally on my VM, but on my development server a query is being wrongfully encoded. In one of my controllers, I have a redirect:

```
return Redirect::action('CustomerController@index', array('search'=>$term));
```

Locally, it resolves correctly to: example.com/customer?**search=Smith**

On the development server, it's resolving to: example.com/customer?**search%3dSmith**

I've tried digging into the redirect class and found where toRoute() has a list of replacement "don't encode" strings:

```
protected function toRoute($route, array $parameters, $absolute)
{
    $domain = $this->getRouteDomain($route, $parameters);

    $uri = strtr(rawurlencode($this->trimUrl(
        $root = $this->replaceRoot($route, $domain, $parameters),
        $this->replaceRouteParameters($route->uri(), $parameters)
    )), $this->dontEncode).$this->getRouteQueryString($parameters);
    return $absolute ? $uri : '/'.ltrim(str_replace($root, '', $uri), '/');
}

protected $dontEncode = array(
    '%2F' => '/',
    '%40' => '@',
    '%3A' => ':',
    '%3B' => ';',
    '%2C' => ',',
    '%3D' => '=',
    '%2B' => '+',
    '%21' => '!',
    '%2A' => '*',
    '%7C' => '|',
);
```

But I believe this is not applied to the second part of the url in getRouteQueryString($parameters);  But then again, this part just uses http_build_query and isn't part of the rawurlencode. So I don't know why the array I'm passing to the route action is getting the '=' encoded.